# Symfony Virtual Server Amazon Ubuntu

Tags: php, security, symfony, amazon-web-services

I have project Symfony in local and hosting heroku. Yesterday I deploy in Virtual Server Amazon, Ubunut 14.04. I check for all problem for symfony (check.php):

[this is](http://ec2-52-16-21-37.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/my_check.php)

in Virtual Server Ubuntu and clone project, config vhost. And when I doing regisrtation company and , in local and another hosting work good, and when I want to enter in my credenials

```
http://artelfreelancedb/app_dev.php/auth/login_check
```

I have:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: serialize(): &quot;id&quot; returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist in /var/www/artel-freelancedb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php line 160
```

What Iam doing wrong? In local work in fortrabit work in heroku work

I try in my entity fields protected but still problem. In auth action must be email and password credentials (In Entity SUser) (I try protected bit no)

```
<?php
namespace Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Users
*
* @ORM\Table(name="users")
*      @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\Repository\UsersR    epository")
*/

class Users extends SUser
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="web_site", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $webSite;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="employees", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $employees;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="markets", type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $markets = array();

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="technologies", type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $technologies = array();

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="string", length=40, nullable=true)
 */
private $zip;

/**
 * @var \Cities
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cities")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="otherCities", type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $otherCities;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Artel\CustomerBundle\Entity\Feedback", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $feedback;
```

Help please

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, add this methos for my entity.

```
public function __sleep(){
return array('id', 'username', 'email');
}
```

But Im not understand why in local work fine and heroku and fortrabit but in Virtual server have this trable ???